# App.yaml on app engine is not forwarding wildcards properly

Tags: python, html, angularjs, google-app-engine

I tried recently to enable html5mode browsing in angular with

```
// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Suddenly though, when I try to go to one of my client side routes, app engine seems not to even forward my request to my webapp2 handler.

For example, localhost:8080/#/myRoute routes properly when entered directly but localhost:8080/myRoute gives me a 404.

I recognize # indicates a client side route, but as long as my request is forwarded to my index.html angular should handle the request.  I didn't explicitly create a route for /#/ so it seems like it's handling those as wildcards but not other routes.

I tried these routes in my app.yaml:

```
- url: /
  script: server.web_server.main.app

- url: .*
  script: server.web_server.main.app

- url: /.*
  script: server.web_server.main.app
```

My server.web_server.main.app routing setup looks like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    # Main SPA handler
    webapp2.Route('/', MainHandler, name='main'),
], debug=True)
```

MainHandler never even sees a request when I don't use # and the server logs indicate indeed they did have a 404.  I could understand if both # and nothing caused a 404 then my wildcards would not be working properly, but why would /#/ work and / not work if I haven't put any special routing for /#/?

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
-- Jp.

Answer (score 1):

`MainHandler` isn't seeing a request for `/myRoute` because only `/` is being routed (within the app) to that handler, even though your `app.yaml` is routing requests *to* the app.

Try adding something like

```
webapp2.Route('/myRoute', MainHandler, name='myroutemain'),
```

to the `WSGIApplication`.

Comment: So I still don't totally see why this follows.  If this was true, why would /#/ route properly?

I don't really want to take this approach either.  I'd like to have any and all routes client side be defined in one place and isolated from all server routing.

Comment: When a browser sends `/#/foo` to a web server, dispatch is based off the leading `/`, which you have a route for. The remainder is stripped off. There's some useful background info on this in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics

Answer (score 0):

So the post above is totally correct, but I thought I would add an even simpler solution solution which doesn't require you to hand specify each client side route.

You can add a wildcard regex by doing the following:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, opt=None):
        self.render("index.html", {"title": "My Angular App"})

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    # Main SPA handler
    webapp2.Route(r'/<:.*>', MainHandler, name='main')
], debug=True)
```

I didn't quite have the syntax right for the regex when I tried originally.  The captured value gets passed to get which you can use if you want.

Comment: As an aside, I got this solution from:
https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=10